# nssearchfield predictate doesnt return items with spaces

Tags: cocoa-bindings, nspredicate

```
ANY contains $value.lowercaseString
```

above is the value I place into my xib's bindings search predicate.

if I type in a word such as =>  happy 
it returns correctly 
if I type in a word such as => happy luck

then my view no longer will contain the a result.  even though happy luck does exist as a searchable data point.

All in all it sorts a list of items in a collection view.

I have read this:

[Collapse sequences of white space into a single character and trim string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/objective-c-strip-out-whitespace-from-nsstring)

and I have read this:

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/11/25/adding-itunes-style-search-to-your-core-data-application/

but its kinda not syncing in.

I want to be able to take the searchString entered into my NSSearchField and strip out the spaces so that I can then feed it to my bindings and have it sort the arrangedObjects.  Comparing the whitespace stripped prediate against each whitespace stripd item in the NSArrayControllers arrangedObjects.

Just don't get how to do it.

Comment: I've never seen that `.lowercaseString` syntax, where did you get it?

Comment: i took that out and behavior is still messed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that I was pulling the search string as absoluteString, which injected %20's into the searchString name which didn't validate correctly against the NSSearchField's predicate.

so I used path instead of abosluteString this deals out a workable string for predicate comparison.