# How to separate string by space using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, whitespace

Assume that I have a String like this:

```
hello world       this may     have lots   of sp:ace or little      space
```

I would like to seperate this String to this:

```
@"hello", @"world", @"this", @"may", @"have", @"lots", @"of", @"sp:ace", @"or", @"little", @"space"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your recipe is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/objective-c-strip-out-whitespace-from-nsstring/1427224#1427224

Comment: I can't see, why this question is voted as "not a real question". The OP says what is given and what is needed to achieve.

Answer (score 81):

```
NSString *aString = @"hello world       this may     have lots   of sp:ace or little      space";
NSArray *array = [aString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
array = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"]];
```

Answer (score 23):

I'd suggest a two-step aproach:

```
NSArray *wordsAndEmptyStrings = [yourLongString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSArray *words = [wordsAndEmptyStrings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
```

Answer (score 23):

This has worked for me

```
NSString * str = @"Hi Hello How Are You ?";
NSArray * arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"Array values are : %@",arr);
```

Comment: What if the characters in the input string are separated by more than one space (as is the case in this question)?

Answer (score 5):

It's very easy to do this with blocks, try something like this :

```
NSString* s = @"hello world       this may     have lots   of space or little      space";
NSMutableArray* ar = [NSMutableArray array];
[s enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [s length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString* word, NSRange wordRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL* stop){
    [ar addObject:word];
}];
```