# Comparing String to Array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm trying to get a word from a label and compare it to an text file, but for some reason I get "no" for a response no matter what i do. is there something wrong with the code.

```
wordS1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"c" ofType:@"txt"];
wordS2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:wordS1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];        
wordArray = [wordS2   componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];


for (compare = 0 ; compare != 58; compare++) 
{

    if ( [word.text isEqualToString:[wordArray objectAtIndex:compare]]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Yes");    

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that there is some unwanted white space in the strings from the text file. Try changing `isEqualToString` to `hasPrefix`.

EDIT: that's actually not the best way to do it. Look here for removing the whitespace from the string [Collapse sequences of white space into a single character and trim string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/objective-c-strip-out-whitespace-from-nsstring)

Comment: try adding `NSLog(@"Label Text: %@",word.text); NSLog(@"WordArray Text: %@",[wordArray objectAtIndex:compare]);` right before the for loop. See if any of the strings actually are equal.

Comment: Did that and the words are the same. I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: What if you use `isEqualTo` instead of `isEqualToString`?

Comment: did to mean isEqual. because that has the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for your help. turns out it was the white space.