# Why doesn't isEqualToString work the way I think it should?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm loading a UTF-8 encoded text file into an array.  At several places in the text file there are blank lines, with no spaces.

In this conditional:

```
tempstring = [array objectAtIndex:index];
if( [tempstring isEqualToString:@""] == NO ) {
    // do something
}
```

The result is always NO.  I NSLog the strings, but I don't see any character in the console on the blank lines.  The NSLog also shows the blank lines having the length of 1.

How can I correct this conditional to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the whitespace from the NSString from the NSArray before comparing it. See here: [Collapse sequences of white space into a single character and trim string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/objective-c-strip-out-whitespace-from-nsstring)

Comment: Perfect: tempstring= [tempstring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Answer (score 0):

Blank lines are usually not completely blank - they still have a newline at the end, even when they have nothing else. Try this:

```
tempstring = [array objectAtIndex:index];
if( [tempstring isEqualToString:@"\n"] == NO ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: If that fails, but stripping whitespace works, that means you don't have blank lines - you have lines with one or more whitespace characters in them.

Comment: strange, whitespace doesn't show in the text file in xcode.  :|  But what you say makes sense.  Could it be added when it's loaded into the array? array = [self loadTextFileNamed:filename];

Comment: must be newline char, not whitespace

Comment: I don't know what -loadTextFileNamed: is doing - you wrote it, not me. :-) If it's using `-componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"` to split the string into lines, then a DOS text file with \r\n line endings could confuse it, and leave the \r at the end of each line. If that's the case, and handling such files is a requirement, you should split with `-componentsSeparatedByCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]` instead. IMHO, it's better to solve problems at their source, than to work around them elsewhere.

Comment: Blah, typo. Make that: `-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]`.

Answer (score -1):

tempstring = [array objectAtIndex:index];

if( [tempstring isEqualToString:@""] == FALSE && tempstring != nil ) {

```
// do something
```

}