# How to remove whitespace in a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a string say `"Allentown,   pa"`

How to remove the white space in between `,` and `pa` using objective c?

Answer (score 66):

This will remove all space from `myString`.

```
NSString *newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: @VanDuTran this was written long ago. I'm not working with iOS for few years, so can't help with iOS 9 right now. Sorry.

Comment: No prob, I just wanted to point that out. It doesn't work for " " space character.

Comment: it does not work in iOS9. Apple just bended the rules without anyone knowing it? Such a basic function.. How many devs will suffer this change since iOS9?

Answer (score 31):

Here is a proper and documented way of removing white spaces from your string.

***whitespaceCharacterSet*** Apple Documentation for iOS says:

```
Returns a character set containing only the in-line whitespace characters space (U+0020) and tab (U+0009).

+ (id)whitespaceCharacterSet
Return Value
A character set containing only the in-line whitespace characters space (U+0020) and tab (U+0009).

Discussion
This set doesn’t contain the newline or carriage return characters.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
```

You can use this documented way:

```
[yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Hope this helps you.

If you need any more help then please let me know on this.

Comment: Just to note: this only trims whitespace at the beginning and end of a string, not in the middle.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - it may be correct for trimming characters and the beginning and end, but it doesn't do what the OP wants which is remove white space from inside the string.

Comment: This would be the shortest hack:
`[[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""]`

Comment: @Fjölnir: You are correct. I was a novice back then. Didn't know details about it then.

Comment: Fjölnir's little comment here should be the accepted answer! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Probably the solution in one of the answers in [Collapse sequences of white space into a single character and trim string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/how-can-i-strip-all-the-whitespaces-from-a-string-in-objective-c):

```
NSString *whitespaceString = @" String with whitespaces ";

NSString *trimmedString = [whitespaceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: Now what if the string contains multiple spaces consecutively?

Comment: mapping " " to "" will still handle multiple spaces consecutively

Answer (score 9):

If you want to white-space and new-line character as well then use "**whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet**" instead of "**whitespaceCharacterSet**"

```
 NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
 NSString *trimmedString = [temp.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];

 NSLog(@"Value of the text field is %@",trimmedString);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myStr = [myStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *sample = @" string with whitespaces";
NSString *escapeWhiteSpaces = [sample stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSString *)removeWhitespaces {
  return [[self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
      componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Comment: It didn't have proper code formatting and indentation for better visibility. Whole code was displayed in one line.

Answer (score 1):

In my case NSString was added Zero Width Space(i i used some library). so solution worked for me.

```
NSMutableString *newString=[[newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u200B" withString:@""] mutableCopy];
```

@"\u200B" is Zero width space character value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper way to remove extra whitespaces from string which is coming in between.

```
NSString *yourString = @"Allentown,   pa";
NSCharacterSet *whitespaces = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSPredicate *noEmptyStrings = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];

NSArray *parts = [yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:whitespaces];
NSArray *filteredArray = [parts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:noEmptyStrings];
yourString = [filteredArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use remove function to remove any substring from the string

```
- (NSString*)remove:(NSString*)textToRemove fromString:(NSString*)input { 
    return [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:textToRemove withString:@""]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the solutions here, none of them could remove the whitespace generated by the Chinese PinYin Input method.

After some debugging, I found this working:

```
NSString *newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\342\200\206" withString:@""];
```

I have googled what the **'\342\200\206'** is, but failed.

Whatever, it works for me.

Comment: @Rambatino No. I was sending the string to a remote server and found it from the server log. I thought it also can be seen during the Xcode's debugging mode.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is the swift version of the solution with extension :

```
extension String{
    func deleteSpaces() -> String{
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    }
}
```

And Just call

```
(yourString as! String).deleteSpaces()
```

Answer (score -3):

Swift 3:

```
var word: String = "Hello world"
let removeWhiteSpace = word.stringByRemovingWhitespaces
word = "Helloworld"
```

Comment: ?  just use the example I used above, instead of word, use your string