# How to trim whitespaces in an NSString

Tags: objective-c

I am having an NSString object as "HAI HELLO ABC".I want it to "HAIHELLOABC".Is there any function present?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove whitespace in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608420/how-to-remove-whitespace-in-a-string)

Comment: You can also use stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: see the example below.

Ex: NSString *string = @"HAI ABC HELLO";
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString * newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```