# Remove all whitespaces from NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, nsstring

I've been trying to get rid of the white spaces in an `NSString`, but none of the methods I've tried worked.

I have `"this is a test"` and I want to get `"thisisatest"`.

I've used `whitespaceCharacterSet`, which is supposed to eliminate the white spaces.

```
NSString *search = [searchbar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

but I kept getting the same string with spaces. Any ideas?

Comment: There is not a simple way, but this link has great answers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/how-can-i-strip-all-the-whitespaces-from-a-string-in-objective-c

Comment: @Adel But, no accepted answers =)

Answer (score 307, accepted):

`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only removes characters from the beginning and the end of the string, not the ones in the middle.

**1)** If you need to remove only a given character (say the space character) from your string, use:

```
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
```

**2)** If you really need to remove a set of characters (namely not only the space character, but any whitespace character like space, tab, unbreakable space, etc), you could split your string using the `whitespaceCharacterSet` then joining the words again in one string:

```
NSArray* words = [yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString* nospacestring = [words componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

*Note that this last solution has the advantage of handling every whitespace character and not only spaces, but is a bit less efficient that the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`. So if you really only need to remove the space character and are sure you won't have any other whitespace character than the plain space char, use the first method.*

Answer (score 35):

**I prefer using regex like this:**

```
NSString *myString = @"this is a test";
NSString *myNewString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s"
                                     withString:@""
                                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [myStringlength])];
 //myNewString will be @"thisisatest"
```

---

**You can make yourself a category on NSString to make life even easier:**

```
- (NSString *) removeAllWhitespace
{
    return [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s" withString:@""
                                              options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];
```

}

**Here is a unit test method on it too:**

```
- (void) testRemoveAllWhitespace
{
    NSString *testResult = nil;

    NSArray *testStringsArray        = @[@""
                                         ,@"    "
                                         ,@"  basicTest    "
                                         ,@"  another Test \n"
                                         ,@"a b c d e f g"
                                         ,@"\n\tA\t\t \t \nB    \f  C \t  ,d,\ve   F\r\r\r"
                                         ,@"  landscape, portrait,     ,,,up_side-down   ;asdf;  lkjfasdf0qi4jr0213 ua;;;;af!@@##$$ %^^ & *  * ()+  +   "
                                         ];

    NSArray *expectedResultsArray   = @[@""
                                        ,@""
                                        ,@"basicTest"
                                        ,@"anotherTest"
                                        ,@"abcdefg"
                                        ,@"ABC,d,eF"
                                        ,@"landscape,portrait,,,,up_side-down;asdf;lkjfasdf0qi4jr0213ua;;;;af!@@##$$%^^&**()++"
                                        ];

    for (int i=0; i < [testStringsArray count]; i++)
    {
        testResult = [testStringsArray[i] removeAllWhitespace];
        STAssertTrue([testResult isEqualToString:expectedResultsArray[i]], @"Expected: \"%@\" to become: \"%@\", but result was \"%@\"",
                     testStringsArray[i], expectedResultsArray[i], testResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I like this included unit tests business. Now not only can I copy-paste my code from SO, but I can also copy-paste the tests for that code!

Answer (score 13):

Easy task using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

```
NSString *search = [searchbar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: Agree, however, only if you don't need the set of whitespace.  I was going to use that, but then realized I had new-lines in my string.

Answer (score 7):

This may help you if you are experiencing `\u00a0` in stead of    (whitespace). I had this problem when I was trying to extract Device Contact Phone Numbers. I needed to modify the phoneNumber string so it has no whitespace in it.

```
NSString* yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@""];
```

When `yourString` was the current phone number.

Comment: This helped a ton! I was stuck on that too! Thanks a lot man! :D

Comment: For swift 3 you can use `yourString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{00a0}", with: "")`

Answer (score 4):

stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString will replace all white space with in the string non only the starting and end

Use

```
[YourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet  whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
```

Comment: you say to use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` but give an example of `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`?

Answer (score 4):

This for me is the best way   SWIFT

```
        let myString = "  ciao   \n              ciao     "
        var finalString = myString as NSString

        for character in myString{
        if character == " "{

            finalString = finalString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

        }else{
            finalString = finalString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "")

        }

    }
     println(finalString)
```

and the result is :  ciaociao

But the trick is this!

```
 extension String {

    var NoWhiteSpace : String {

    var miaStringa = self as NSString

    if miaStringa.containsString(" "){

      miaStringa =  miaStringa.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    }
        return miaStringa as String

    }
}

let myString = "Ciao   Ciao       Ciao".NoWhiteSpace  //CiaoCiaoCiao
```

Answer (score 4):

```
- (NSString *)removeWhitespaces {
  return [[self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
      componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, a few words of explanation would go a long way to making this answer valuable to future readers.

Answer (score 3):

That is for removing any space that is when you getting text from any text field but if you want to remove space between string you can use

```
xyz =[xyz.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

It will replace empty space with no space and empty field is taken care of by below method:

```
searchbar.text=[searchbar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below marco and remove the space.

```
#define TRIMWHITESPACE(string) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
```

in other file call TRIM :

```
    NSString *strEmail;
    strEmail = TRIM(@"     this is the test.");
```

May it will help you...

Answer (score -1):

```
pStrTemp = [pStrTemp stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Please, elaborate a bit on what this snippet does and fix its formatting.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suggest placing this somewhere in your project:

```
extension String {
    func trim() -> String {
        return self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    }

    func trim(withSet: NSCharacterSet) -> String {
        return self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(withSet)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.