# How to remove blank spaces from a string in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, nscharacterset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing one character in a string in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223701/replacing-one-character-in-a-string-in-objective-c)
>   [Remove all whitespace from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628470/remove-all-whitespace-from-nsstring)

`@"this string contains     blank spaces"`.

How can we convert this string into `@"thisstringcontainsblankspaces"`.

I mean how can we trim all the blank spaces and new line charecters in a string. I have already tried `NSCharecterSet` by using `whitespaceCharacterSet`. But this only removes the spaces at the ends of the string and not in between....

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to remove the white space:

```
NSString *str    =  @"this string contains blank spaces";
NSString *newStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
[YourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

You can pass any character or word which you want to replace at

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
```

and replacing word/string/character:

```
withString:@" "
```

Enjoy coding.