# How to parse numbers from NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *numberVector = @"( 1, 2, 3, 4)";
```

I want to get NSMutableArray from these numbers.
How can I do this?

Comment: could you provide code snip for me?

Comment: you got the answer from DrummerB

Comment: today only similar question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515905/extract-digits-from-string-in-obj-c/15516109#15516109

Comment: You shoould not edit your question, once answers are there. Then answer may not match with your edited question.

Comment: I tried to post question code from paste, \n were removed in the original question.

Comment: But still, what @AnoopVaidya said. Don't change relevant information in your question once there are answers (or at all actually). Either add an "EDIT:" tag and add new information below or ask a new question.

Comment: That looks as if you had stored an array into a string using the `numberVector = [myArray description]` method or `numberVector = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myArray]`. Perhaps there is a better solution than to store the array in a string?

Comment: AS Martin said, if this is the case, you are rotating around for no reason.

Comment: once check my answer it'l helps you ,in that you can give any type of string it gives an array with the numbers only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simpler one, convert it to json string first then convert is to array using `NSJSONSerialization`

```
NSString *numberVector = @"( 1, 2, 3, 4)";
numberVector = [numberVector stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"["];
numberVector = [numberVector stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"]"];
NSError* error;
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[numberVector dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

**Update**

This will work for both `@"( 1, 2, 3, 4)"` and `@"(\n 1,\n 2,\n 3,\n 4\n)"` as json string can have new line and spaces.

**P.S** This will work for iOS 5.0 or greater for other iOS you can use SBJSON or other parsing library available.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization ios >5.0 (Available in iOS 5.0 and later.)

Comment: @EvgeniyS for <5.0 you can use any json library

Answer (score 1):

If you know that this is exactly your format and don't have to be flexible in the amount of spaces, brackets or commas:

```
NSCharacterSet *trimSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ()"];
numberVector = [numberVector stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:trimSet];
NSArray *numbers = [numberVector componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this it'l works fine for any type of data it accepts only numbers.

```
NSString *numberVector = @"(\n 1,\n 2,\n 3,\n 4\n)";

    NSString *onlyNumbers = [numberVector  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9,]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [numberVector  length])];
    NSArray *numbers=[onlyNumbers componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"%@",numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below, it should work:

```
  NSCharacterSet *cSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ()"];  
  numberVector = [numberVector stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:cSet];
  //specify delimiter below
  NSArray *numbers = [numberVector componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

Answer (score -2):

With this:

```
NSString *numberVector = @"( 1, 2, 3, 4)";
```

EDIT

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"&([^;])*;" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [numberVector stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];

NSArray *listItems = [[modifiedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]
```