# Objective-C NSMutableString How to remove leading and trailing spaces?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

In Objective-C, how do you removed leading and trailing spaces from an occurrence of NSMutableString?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collapse sequences of white space into a single character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/collapse-sequences-of-white-space-into-a-single-character)

Comment: @Larme I don't think that's quite a duplicate, as this is just about trimming, but hard to imagine there isn't a duplicate _somewhere_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `string` is a mutable string:

```
[string setString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];
```

Comment: Shouldn't `self` be `string`? This doesn't appear to be a category method.

Comment: Yes, I copied from a comment I made on a category answer!

Comment: Thank you. I found that exact same answer someplace else as well. As is probably obvious, I'm extremely new to Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression:

```
[string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"(^\\s+)|(\\s+$)" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Comment: Thank you. GREP is a favorite of mine. But didn't know how to use it with mutable strings.