# Replace stretches of spaces and newlines with just a space in a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I was wondering if there is a library or easy way that allows me to take an `NSString` and replace any stretch of '\n' and spaces that are strung together with just a single space? (included in this, I also just want to replace all occurrences of '\n' by itself with a  space). So I'd want to take an `NSString` like this:

```
bla     bla  
    bla bla
```

and convert it to this:

```
bla bla bla bla
```

I've looked around and it seems the only it can be done is manually. Does anyone know if there is another way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/collapse-sequences-of-white-space-into-a-single-character ? And using the `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` instead for the `NSCharacterSet`?

Comment: @Larme Yeah I think essentially that is what Matt had below. Wasn't able to find that question. Thanks for posting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always in these situations, I am a huge fan of regular expressions. How did we ever get along without them? So I would call `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString...` with the `options:` including the regular expression specifier, and use a simple pattern expression that finds all stretches of whitespace (and replaces it with a single space).

```
NSString* s2 = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s+" 
 withString:@" " 
 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch 
 range:NSMakeRange(0,s.length)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just separate string by `\n` and join it using spaces.

```
NSString *result = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

This will remove new lines, to collapse sequence of whitespaces into single whitespace, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/collapse-sequences-of-white-space-into-a-single-character)