# Remove White spaces between words in a NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, space

I am getting data from server and lot unexpected spaces between the words. like below

```
NSString* str = @"This   is Test  Result ".
```

The extras must be remove like there must be only one space between `This` and `is`.

If we use the below only `leading` and `trailing` spaces will be removed, but I need different

```
NSString *trimmedString = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/collapse-sequences-of-white-space-into-a-single-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
NSString *properString= [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"[ \t]+"
                                                             withString: @" "
                                                                options: NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                  range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
```

your result will be : "This is Test Result "